# Knockoutjs Validation

Tags: validation, knockout.js

I am facing a problem with my validation

Here is my field with extend property

```
self.searchText = ko.observable("")
                    .extend({ pattern: { params: /^[a-zA-Z0-9\åäöÅÄÖ]+$/g, message: "Invalid symbols."} });
```

Regex is well to not allow special symbols But, in runtime I can enter any symbol

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: You are validating your viewmodel, meaning when you do the validation, the viewmodel has already been updated. If you want to prevent the input, you'll need additional code on your fields (check the `input` event for example)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the problem you're actually trying to solve is "use knockout to prevent special characters", not "use knockout to tell them that they've used special characters", then you'll want something like this:

```
var allowedChars = /[a-zA-Z0-9\åäöÅÄÖ]/;

var _noSpecialCharacters = ko.observable("");
self.searchText = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        //read underlying observable
        return _noSpecialCharacters();
    },
    write: function (newVal) {
        //filter disallowed characters
        var filtered = newVal.split("").filter(function (char) {
            return allowedChars.test(char)
        }).join("")
        //write to underlying observable
        _noSpecialCharacters(filtered);
    }
});
```

You could also wrap this functionality into a custom knockout extension pretty easily, which would let you use syntax like what you're trying to use in the question.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xQ53/2/)